# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" When using sample code on express-vue readme

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I copied the sample code that can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-vue

I installed the babel packages that it suggested and added the recommended files.

I then changed the route code that it provided from:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const data: {
        otherData: 'Something Else' 
    };
    req.vueOptions: {
        head: {
            title: 'Page Title',
            metas: [
                { property:'og:title', content: 'Page Title'},
                { name:'twitter:title', content: 'Page Title'},
            ]
        }    
    }
    res.renderVue('main.vue', data, req.vueOptions);
})
```

to:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  req.vueOptions: {
    head: {
      title: 'Pharaoh',
    }
  }
  res.renderVue('App.vue', data, req.vueOptions);
})
```

nodemon throws me an error in the console that says the following:

```
req.vueOptions: {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I guess it should be `req.vueOptions = {`

Comment: Yes @StephenS is right. Have a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/express-vue/express-vue/pull/211/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R107) from someone else who seems to also have run into this issue.